# How can I export graph as PDF with metadata such as Title and Author fields

Tags: graphics, export, bugs, pdf-format, metadata

I want to export a figure from *Mathematica* in PDF format. Moreover, I want to fill Author and Title fields of the PDF. For example, to fill Author field, I use the following code:

```
pp = Plot[{x^2}, {x, -1, 1}]
Export["plot-example.pdf", pp, "Author" -> "Dmitry"]
```

However, when I open generated PDF file in a PDF viewer, the "Author" field is not filled.

How should I specify Export call to include Author and Title fields in the generated PDF file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44255/10397
But the answer there was not satisfactory as its OS dependent.

Comment: Furthermore, all the `.pdf` export seems to be flawed as the export with attachments described in the documentation doesn't work either.

Comment: @rhermans The attachments work here (V9), but not the Author, Creator, etc

Comment: I didn't see any attachments in the pdf when I tried v10. Anybody else can confirm?

Comment: @rhermans Indeed, the attachment example for PDF in the help browser doesn't work for me in version 10.1 on OS X. So I agree that PDF export is suffering from multiple bugs.

Comment: I've added the bugs tag because the comments confirm that this should work and does not. I have reported this as  [CASE:3422830].

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One could do a string replacement on `ExportString` to add the data, but of course that may crash with large files... so the only reliable methods I can think of would require external tools (or patience if you want to wait for Wolfram to fix the bug).

Comment: @Jens I am open to the use of an external utility if it is not too complicated and does not have an overly large system footprint.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  PDF supports **Incremental Update** and random access, so we don't need to read large files complete, and only need to append the modifications. In this case we would only need to append a new version of the info and metadata sections. See my answer.

Comment: By the way, just replacing the PDF content would mess up with the cross reference (xref) section that list the memory positions of each component for random access.

Answer (score 22):

The package and all code of this answer can [be found on my GitHub account](https://github.com/halirutan/PDFMetaData).

---

A solution that takes only small amount of time is to follow this route:

- take the first [usable java library](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) for accessing and changing PDF files you find
- do one of the following:

  - write a small amount of Java code to create a simple interface to the functionality (if you are interested, this design pattern is call [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern))
  - use the *Mathematica* functions of `` JLink` `` directly to access the PDF library. This is often harder to read IMO and I would recommend this only in rare cases
- write a small *Mathematica* package that can be loaded and provides you with a high-level function to call the Java library

The structure of the finished package layout can be as easy as this

```
PDFMetaData
├── Java
│   └── PDFMetaData.jar
└── PDFMetaData.m
```

In this simple case `PDFMetaData.m` contains a function like this

```
SetPDFMetaData[file_String][meta : {(_String -> _String)..}] := JavaBlock[
  InstallJava[];
  LoadJavaClass["de.halirutan.pdfmetadata.PDFMetaDataSetter",
    StaticsVisible -> True];
  PDFMetaDataSetter`setMetaData[file, Flatten[List @@@ meta]]
];
```

The static Java function that is called at the end, is [rather simple too](https://github.com/halirutan/PDFMetaData/blob/master/src/de/halirutan/pdfmetadata/PDFMetaDataSetter.java). I should note, that I have compiled my source and packed the created class file together with the `PDF` library itself into `PDFMetaData.jar`. This `jar` is now selfcontained.

The package needs to be put into a place where *Mathematica* can find it, like

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

This is especially important, because then, the `Java` folder is automatically added to the java `CLASSPATH`.

Well, that's basically it. Go and use it

```
<< PDFMetaData`

SetPDFMetaData[
  Export["tmp/meta.pdf", "Hello"]][{"Author" -> "Xavier Breath", 
  "Title" -> "Stop Arguing!", "Creator" -> "Funny Inc.", 
  "Producer" -> "Nick R. Elastic",
  "Keywords" -> "Mathematica PDF"}]
```

[image]

---

Final note, please just change the call pattern of `SetPDFMetaData[file][metalist]` to `SetPDFMetaData[file, metalist]` if you feel more comfortable with it. I had no specific reason to use `SubValues`.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick.  This is wonderfully easy to install and use.  If this were my Question I would Accept this.

Comment: Incidentally do you know of an easy way to "lock" a PDF file to prevent modification but still allow printing?  (I know such measures are defeatable but it still lets responsible people know it's not supposed to be modified.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, in theory it's pretty simple and a basic example can be [found here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/encryption.html). The problem is, it doesn't work on my machine. What you want is to set certain permissions and then encrypt the pdf without a user password. With this, the user can open the pdf, but is only allowed to do certain operations. To gain complete access, you would need to give the *owner password* which is `1234` in the linked example. I already added this to the package, but as I said, for me it doesn't work. If you want I can still push it so you can testIt

Comment: If you feel like providing a wrapper for it I am curious to test it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have pushed the version to the repository but I'm pretty sure it won't work. I have created a [unit test](https://github.com/halirutan/PDFMetaData/blob/master/tests/de/halirutan/pdfmetadata/PDFLockerTest.java) where I lock a test-pdf and verify that afterwards the permission are still not set correctly. For the *Mathematica* package, I have added a [PDFLock](https://github.com/halirutan/PDFMetaData/blob/master/PDFMetaData/PDFMetaData.m) function.

Answer (score 13):

From the [PDF file definitions](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (7.5.4 - 7.5.6) you don't need to modify the inner structure of a PDF file to make changes, its enough to append the new definitions of the components (New or old) and suitable cross-reference section with pointers to the shift positions of some relevant components for random access.

Here I attempt some code to do all the work in *Mathematica*.
It still needs some polishing, probably with some help I could write a reasonable package.

#### needed improvements

- Currently it is also only modifying the **"/Info"** section, not the **"Metadata"** but that is doable in the same way.
- I'm sure most of the parsing, writing and strings operations can be done in a more clever and compact way too.
- It assumes a single **xref** subsection, which would be true for fresh *Mathematica* generated files, but not universal.

#### Edits

- Now it quits gracefully if the file isn't writable.
- The **"ModDate"** for last modified date is updated

## Usage:

```
 fn = "test.PDF";
 Export[fn, α];
 pdfWriteInfo[fn, {
   "Title" -> "Alpha"
 , "Producer" -> "Mod by RH"
 , "Author" -> $UserName
 , "Subject" -> "mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59270"
 , "Keywords" -> "PDF,Mathematica"
 }]
```

> [image: PDF metadata]

## PDF code

we are dealing whith this portion of plaintext at the end of the PDF

[image]

### Define PDF Readout functions

Open the file to read the last 30 bytes, finds the "startxref" and reads the shift position of "xref". Checks that the files ends in "%%EOF".

#### Read position of cross reference

We need this to avoid a long search in a potentially huge file.

```
pdfReadStartXref::notPDF = "`1` does not comply with the PDF format";
pdfReadStartXref[file_String] := If[
  FileExistsQ[file],
  Block[{fs, sxref} (* File Stream ; Start of Cross refference*),
   fs = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
   SetStreamPosition[fs, -30];
   If[Find[fs, "startxref"] === EndOfFile, Close[fs]; 
    Message[pdfReadStartXref::notPDF, file]; Return[Null]];
   sxref = Read[fs, Number];
   If[Find[fs, "%%EOF"] === EndOfFile, Close[fs]; 
    Message[pdfReadStartXref::notPDF, file]; Return[Null]];
   Close[fs];
   sxref
   ]]
```

test

```
pdfReadStartXref[fn]
```

> ```
>  4041
> ```

That number we use to [`SetStreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetStreamPosition.html) next to the ***xref*** and ***trailer*** section.

#### Read trailer

```
pdfReadTrailer[file_String, esxref_: 0] := If[
  FileExistsQ[file],
  Block[{filestream, startxref, trailer, starttrailer} (* 
   File Stream *),
   filestream = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
   startxref = If[
     esxref === 0,
     SetStreamPosition[filestream, -30];
     Read[
      StringToStream[
       Read[filestream, Record, 
        RecordSeparators -> {{"startxref"}, {"%%EOF"}}]], Number],
     esxref
     ];
   SetStreamPosition[filestream, startxref];
   Find[filestream, "trailer"];
   starttrailer = StreamPosition[filestream];
   trailer = Association@Flatten@StringSplit[
       ReadList[
        StringToStream[
         Read[filestream, Record, RecordSeparators -> {{"<<"}, {">>"}}]
         ], Record],
       Shortest[___ ~~ "/" ~~ key__ ~~ Whitespace] ~~ 
         Longest[value___ ~~ EndOfString] :> key -> value];
   Close[filestream];
   {
    starttrailer,
    Map[If[StringMatchQ[#, NumberString], 
       Interpreter["Number"][#], #] &, Map[StringSplit, trailer], {2}]
    }
   ]
  ]
```

test

```
pdfReadTrailer[fn]
```

> ```
>  {4358, <|"Size" -> {15}, "Root" -> {14, 0, "R"}, "Info" -> {13, 0, "R"}|>}
> ```

Now we know that the ***Info*** section is labeled **"13 0"**.

#### Read crossreference

```
pdfReadXRef[file_String, esxref_: 0] := If[
  FileExistsQ[file],
  Block[{filestream, startxref, xref} (* File Stream *),
   startxref = If[esxref === 0, pdfReadStartXref[file], esxref];
   filestream = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
   SetStreamPosition[filestream, startxref];
   Find[filestream, "xref"];
   xref = Association@Table[
        {i -> Read[filestream, {Number, Number, String}]}
        , {i, #1, #1 + #2 - 1}] & @@ Read[filestream, {Number, Number}];
   Close[filestream];
   {startxref, xref}
   ]
  ]
```

test

```
pdfReadXRef[fn]
```

> ```
>  {4041, <|0 -> {0, 65535, " f "}, 1 -> {3721, 0, " n "}, 2 -> {182, 0, " n "},  3 -> {15, 0, " n "}, 4 -> {161, 0, " n "}, 5 -> {3557, 0, " n "}, 6 -> {291, 0, " n "}, 7 -> {502, 0, " n "}, 8 -> {2690, 0, " n "}, 9 -> {2713, 0, " n "}, 10 -> {3015, 0, " n "}, 11 -> {3038, 0, " n "}, 12 -> {3317, 0, " n "}, 13 -> {3786, 0, " n "}, 14 -> {3988, 0, " n "}|>}
> ```

Now we know where in the file is defined each section. We care only for **"13 0"**. The number we were looking for was **"3786"**.

#### Read Info

Now we can `SetStreamPosition` to  **"3786"** where **Info** is defined and read its contents.

```
pdfReadInfo::xref = "Failed parsing xref in file `1` .";
pdfReadInfo[file_String] := If[
  FileExistsQ[file],
  Block[{startxref, xref, trailer, trailerinfo, startInfo, filestream,
     info, infohead, inforef} ,
   {startxref, xref} = pdfReadXRef[file];
   trailer = Last@pdfReadTrailer[file, startxref];
   trailerinfo = trailer["Info"];
   inforef = xref[First[trailerinfo]];
   If[Head[inforef] === Missing, Message[pdfReadInfo::xref, file];,
    startInfo = First[inforef];
    infohead = Flatten[{Most@trailerinfo, " obj"}];
    filestream = OpenRead[file, BinaryFormat -> True];
    SetStreamPosition[filestream, startInfo];
    If[Read[filestream, {Number, Number, String}] =!= infohead, 
     Abort[]];
    info = Association@Flatten@StringSplit[
        ReadList[
         StringToStream[
          Read[filestream, Record, 
           RecordSeparators -> {{"<<"}, {">>"}}]], Record],
        Shortest[___ ~~ "/" ~~ key__ ~~ Whitespace] ~~ 
          Longest["(" ~~ value___ ~~ ")"] :> key -> value];
    Close[filestream];
    {infohead, info}
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

test

```
pdfReadInfo[fn]
```

> ```
> {{13, 0, " obj"}, <|"Creator" ->  "Wolfram Mathematica 10.2.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)", "Producer" -> "", "CreationDate" -> "20150918133940+01'00", "ModDate" -> "20150918133940+01'00"|>}
> ```

That's the old ***Info*** we will keep that as long as the user doesn't define the same key.

## Write new Info

```
 pdfWriteInfo::nowrite = " `1` file its not writable.";
 pdfWriteInfo[file_String, options_: {"Producer" -> "Code by RH"}] := 
 If[
  FileExistsQ[file],
  Block[{rinfo, infohead, info, newinfo, filestream, newstartxref, 
    oldstartxref, startinfo, trailer, moddatestr} ,
   startinfo = FileByteCount[file];
   If[startinfo > 100,
    oldstartxref = pdfReadStartXref[file];
    rinfo = pdfReadInfo[file];
    If[rinfo =!= Null,
     {infohead, info} = rinfo;
     moddatestr = 
      "D:" <> StringReplace[
        DateString[{"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", 
          "Second", "ISOTimeZone"}], ":" -> "'"] <> "'";
     newinfo = 
      Join[info, Association@options, <|"ModDate" -> moddatestr |>];
     trailer = Last@pdfReadTrailer[file];
     filestream = Check[OpenAppend[file, BinaryFormat -> True], Null];
     If[filestream =!= Null,
       WriteString[filestream, infohead[[1]], " ", infohead[[2]], 
        " obj\r\n<<\r\n"];
       Table[
        WriteString[filestream, "  /", First[item], " (", Last[item], 
         ")\r\n"]
        , {item, Normal[newinfo]}
        ];
       WriteString[filestream, ">>\r\n", "endobj", "\r\n"];
       newstartxref = StreamPosition[filestream];
       WriteString[filestream, "xref\r\n", "0 1\r\n", 
        "0000000000 65535 f\r\n", infohead[[1]], " ", infohead[[2]], 
        "\r\n",
        IntegerString[startinfo, 10, 10], " ", 
        IntegerString[infohead[[2]], 10, 5], " n\r\n", 
        "trailer\r\n<<"];
       Table[
        WriteString[filestream, "  /", First[item2], " ", 
         Sequence @@ Riffle[Last[item2], " "], "\r\n"]
        , {item2, Normal[trailer]}];
       WriteString[filestream, "  /Prev ", oldstartxref, "\r\n", 
        ">>\r\n", "startxref\r\n", newstartxref, "\r\n", "%%EOF"];
       ]
      Close[filestream];
     , Message[pdfWriteInfo::nowrite, file]
     ]]]]
```

test

```
pdfWriteInfo[fn, {
  "Title" -> "Alpha"
, "Producer" -> "Mod by RH"
, "Author" -> $UserName}
]
```

*Voila*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such an extensive method!  I'll be checking this later.

Comment: Well, I do have a personal interest on learning how to do this. Suggestions on how to do it better are most welcome. Particularly the parsing and the writing.